# Use http_build_query to increase page query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress instance running on *Server 2012*. I can't install the `http_build_url`. I'm trying create a link that will increase the page query while preserving and other querys that exist in the url. Here's what I've got so far (which doesn't work, the rebuilt URL doesn't include any of the queries from the original url). It also doesn't work if the user is on the first page because page doesn't exist in the array.

**EDIT:** `$user_query` is initialized at the time the code is executed.

Thanks for any help!

```
<?php
$query=$_GET;
$query['page']=$user_query->current_page+1;
$url=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?' .  http_build_query($query);

?>
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?' . $url; ?>">More Pages</a>
```

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**?

Comment: is $user_query initialized at the time this code is executed?

Comment: $user_query is initialized at the time the code is executed.  Marc: The rebuilt URL  doesn't include any of the queries from the original url.

Comment: Do you have an example of a $_GET that should work?